# Fan not spinning after suspend in new kernels (Asus X453M)

Tags: 14.04, kernel, suspend, overheating, fan

More often than not, when my laptop is resumed after being suspended, the fan will no longer spin, resulting in overheating when a heavy process is running.

This happens on Ubuntu 14.04 with 3.13.0 and 3.19.0 kernels.

I had no fan problems on Ubuntu 12.04 with a 3.5.0 kernel.

A reboot (soft or hard) always starts the fan again.

Something which sometime works:

- Shutting the lid and waiting for some time.  When I return and unsuspend the machine, and make it hot, sometimes the fan will start working again!

  (Although then it never stops spinning, even when the temperature drops low.)

Things I have tried which have no effect:

- `sensors-detect` from the lm-sensors cannot find anything beyond `coretemp`
- `fancontrol` service does not start because `pwmconfig` finds nothing to work with
- Kernel options `acpi_osi=Linux`, `=Windows` and `='Windows 2015'`
- `acpi=off` caused the machine to boot with no fan and various other stuff missing
- Flashed the BIOS to latest firmware
- Installed latest `intel-microcode` package

Sensors:

- `sensors` lists three temperatures but no fan speeds.
- `acpi -ci` lists three entries (intel_powerclamp, and two processors) but the values rarely seem to coincide with what I'm hearing

Question:

- **What else has changed that I could try disabling**, either changes in the kernel since 3.5.0, or in Ubuntu between 12.04 and 14.04?

---

Edit: One other thing about my system.  When moving from 12.04/3.5.0 to newer kernels, I had to go into the BIOS and change "OS Selection" from "Windows 8" to "Windows 7" in order for bootup to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Create `/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_fancontrol` with the following contents:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
      /usr/sbin/service fancontrol restart
      ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this does not help because `fancontrol` doesn't work here: neither `sensors-detect` nor `pwmconfig` could find drivers to control my hardware. Under Ubuntu 12.04 I also didn't have `fancontrol` installed, but the fan did stay working after suspend!

Comment: Have you tried latest upstream kernel?

Comment: No you dont that is the point of: '#!/bin/sh'

Comment: Yep, I'm now on `4.2.0-27-generic`.

Comment: 4.4 kernel seems to have got `fancontrol` working, and the problem has now resolved! To get it I installed the package `linux-image-lowlatency-lts-xenial`. Both 4.4.0-14-lowlatency and 4.4.0-22-lowlatency have worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `acpi_osi="!Windows 2012"`? acpi_osi string "Windows 2012" was introduced after 3.5 so disabling it can bring you back to how kernel works with ACPI as in 3.5.

Comment: Thanks. That was actually in my list of things to try, but I haven't tried it yet. It will be my next experiment, and I will let you know next week whether it has worked or not...

Comment: Well this certainly disabled something: `dmesg | grep Windows` shows me `ACPI: Deleted _OSI(Windows 2012)`. But unfortunately the bug persists. However you have reminded me of a change I made to the BIOS when I upgraded. I have appended this to the question, and in time I will test whether it is actually part of the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the behaviour was no different with this kernel option.